error: subprocess-exited-with-error × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully. │ exit code: 1 ╰─> See above for output
i face this error everytime i try to install chatterbot on my python envirement 3.9.13
 error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [95 lines of output]
      Collecting setuptools
        Using cached setuptools-69.5.1-py3-none-any.whl (894 kB)
      Collecting wheel<0.33.0,>0.32.0
        Using cached wheel-0.32.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
      Collecting Cython
        Using cached Cython-3.0.10-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (2.8 MB)
      Collecting cymem<2.1.0,>=2.0.2
        Using cached cymem-2.0.8-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (39 kB)
      Collecting preshed<2.1.0,>=2.0.1
        Using cached preshed-2.0.1.tar.gz (113 kB)
        Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
        Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
      Collecting murmurhash<1.1.0,>=0.28.0
        Using cached murmurhash-1.0.10-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (25 kB)
      Collecting thinc<7.1.0,>=7.0.8
        Using cached thinc-7.0.8-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl
      Collecting tqdm<5.0.0,>=4.10.0
        Using cached tqdm-4.66.2-py3-none-any.whl (78 kB)
      Collecting srsly<1.1.0,>=0.0.6
        Using cached srsly-1.0.7-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (358 kB)
      Collecting plac<1.0.0,>=0.9.6
        Using cached plac-0.9.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
      Collecting wasabi<1.1.0,>=0.0.9
        Using cached wasabi-0.10.1-py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
      Collecting numpy>=1.7.0
        Using cached numpy-1.26.4-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (15.8 MB)
      Collecting blis<0.3.0,>=0.2.1
        Using cached blis-0.2.4.tar.gz (1.5 MB)
        Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
        Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
      Collecting colorama
        Using cached colorama-0.4.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
      Using legacy 'setup.py install' for preshed, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
      Using legacy 'setup.py install' for blis, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
      Installing collected packages: wasabi, plac, cymem, wheel, srsly, setuptools, preshed, numpy, murmurhash, Cython, colorama, tqdm, blis, thinc
        Running setup.py install for preshed: started
        Running setup.py install for preshed: finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error

        Running setup.py install for preshed did not run successfully.
        exit code: 1

        [41 lines of output]
        WARNING: The wheel package is not available.
        running install
        running build
        running build_py
        creating build
        creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
        creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed
        copying preshed\about.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed
        copying preshed\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed
        creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed\tests
        copying preshed\tests\test_counter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed\tests
        copying preshed\tests\test_hashing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed\tests
        copying preshed\tests\test_pop.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed\tests
        copying preshed\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed\tests
        copying preshed\counter.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed
        copying preshed\maps.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed
        copying preshed\counter.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed
        copying preshed\maps.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed
        copying preshed\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed
        running build_ext
        building 'preshed.maps' extension
        creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
        creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
        creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\preshed
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -IC:\Users\ADMIN\cvgenerator\venv\include -IC:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -IC:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um /EHsc /Tppreshed/maps.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\preshed/maps.obj /Ox /EHsc
        maps.cpp
        preshed/maps.cpp(5728): error C2039: 'tp_print' n'est pas membre de '_typeobject'
        C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include\cpython/object.h(193): note: voir la d‚claration de '_typeobject'
        preshed/maps.cpp(5740): error C2039: 'tp_print' n'est pas membre de '_typeobject'
        C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include\cpython/object.h(193): note: voir la d‚claration de '_typeobject'
        preshed/maps.cpp(5749): error C2039: 'tp_print' n'est pas membre de '_typeobject'
        C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include\cpython/object.h(193): note: voir la d‚claration de '_typeobject'
        preshed/maps.cpp(5755): error C2039: 'tp_print' n'est pas membre de '_typeobject'
        C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include\cpython/object.h(193): note: voir la d‚claration de '_typeobject'
        preshed/maps.cpp(5761): error C2039: 'tp_print' n'est pas membre de '_typeobject'
        C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include\cpython/object.h(193): note: voir la d‚claration de '_typeobject'
        preshed/maps.cpp(5767): error C2039: 'tp_print' n'est pas membre de '_typeobject'
        C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include\cpython/object.h(193): note: voir la d‚claration de '_typeobject'
        preshed/maps.cpp(6129): warning C4996: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length': deprecated in 3.3
        preshed/maps.cpp(6145): warning C4996: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length': deprecated in 3.3
        error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.39.33519\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
        [end of output]

        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      error: legacy-install-failure

      Encountered error while trying to install package.

      preshed

      note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
      hint: See above for output from the failure.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

i tried upgrading pip and cheking the c++ compiler an i couldnt soulve it , how can i solve it

You can also use python version 3.8.10 . I have tested chatterbot on this version.
